# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed....when checking for unique key constraint

Tags: jsp, servlets

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
Not able to solve this error plz help

in table i have also assign a unique constraint so when i enter duplicate value it shows this error
JSP Page

```
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
        <jsp:include page="sidepanel.jsp"/>            
        <div id="page-wrapper" >
            <div id="page-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <%
                            Object objCryoboxBarcode = request.getAttribute("txtCryoboxBarcode");
                            Object objContentType = request.getAttribute("txtContentType");
                            Object objLocationCtr = request.getAttribute("txtLocationCtr");
                            Object objSampleStorageCombi = request.getAttribute("txtSampleStorageCombination");
                            // Object objTypeOfStudy = request.getAttribute("TypeOfStudy");

                            String strCryboxBarcode = "";
                            String strContentType = "";
                            String strLocationCtr = "";
                            String strSampleStorageCombination = "";
                              // String strTypeOfStudy = "";
                        %> 
                        <h2>Sample Storage Details for 96 Well format</h2>
                        <form action="AdderCryoboxDeatils96format">
                            <table>
                                <%
                                    Object objErrMsg = request.getAttribute("errMsg");

                                    if (objErrMsg != null) {
                                %>
                                <font color="red">
                                    <b><%= objErrMsg.toString()%></b>
                                </font>
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                <%
                                    }

                                    if (objCryoboxBarcode == null || objContentType == null || objLocationCtr == null) {

                                %>
                                <tr hidden="true">
                                    <td>Content Type : </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="txtContentType" value="Blood Sample" readonly="true" hidden="true"/></td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Type of Study: </td>
                                    <td><select name="txtTypeOfStudy">
                                            <option>Barshi Cohort</option>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr hidden="True">
                                    <td>Sample Storage Temperature : </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="StorageTemp" name="txtStorageTemp" value="0"/></td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sample Storage Box Barcode : </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="txtCryoboxBarcode" onkeypress="movetoNext(this, 'StorageTemp')" /></td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sample Storage Combination : </td>
                                    <td><select name="txtSampleStorageCombination">
                                             <option value="2">96 well format </option>
                                             </select></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="myTextAlign">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Proceed"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                 <%
                                } else {
                                    strCryboxBarcode = objCryoboxBarcode.toString();
                                    strContentType = objContentType.toString();
                                    strLocationCtr = objLocationCtr.toString();
                                    // strTypeOfStudy = objTypeOfStudy.toString();

                                %>
                                <input type="hidden" name="txtCryoboxBarcode" value="<%= strCryboxBarcode%>" />
                                <%
                                    int intLocationCtr = Integer.parseInt(strLocationCtr);

                                    if (intLocationCtr <= 96) {
                                %>

                                <input type="hidden" name="txtContentType" value="<%= strContentType%>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="txtLocationCtr" value="<%= strLocationCtr%>" />

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sample Storage Box Barcode : </td>
                                    <td><%= strCryboxBarcode%></td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--tr>
                                    <td>Content Type : </td>
                                    <td><%= strContentType%></td>
                                </tr-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Scan Sample Barcode: </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="txtBllodSampleBarcode" autofocus="autofocus"/>&nbsp; for Location <b><%= strLocationCtr%></b></td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="myTextAlign">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Proceed"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <%
                                        } else {

                                        }
                                    }
                                %>

                            </table>
                            <br/><br/>

                            <%
                                if (!(objCryoboxBarcode == null || objContentType == null || objLocationCtr == null)) {
                            %>

                            <br/>
                            <table border="1" width="100%">
                                <%
                                    int x = 0;
                                    Barshicohortblood_cryoboxescontentDAO cryDAO = new Barshicohortblood_cryoboxescontentDAO();
                                    Barshicohortblood_cryoboxescontent arrCryoboxescontent[] = cryDAO.getByBoxId(strCryboxBarcode);
                                    String arrCryoVialsDtls[] = new String[96];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrCryoboxescontent.length; i++) {
                                        arrCryoVialsDtls[arrCryoboxescontent[i].getLocation() - 1] = arrCryoboxescontent[i].getCryoVileBarcode();
                                    }
                                %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <% for (int n = 0; n < 12; n++) {%><td align="center"><%= n + 1%></td><%}%>
                                </tr>    
                                <%
                                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                                %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%= (i + 1)%></td>
                                    <%
                                        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                                            if (arrCryoVialsDtls[x] == null) {
                                    %>
                                    <td bgcolor="red" width="8%">
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>    
                                    <%
                                    } else {
                                    %>
                                    <td bgcolor="white" width="8%">
                                        <%= arrCryoVialsDtls[x]%>
                                    </td>    
                                    <%
                                            }
                                            x++;
                                        }
                                    %>
                                </tr>
                                <%
                                    }
                                %>   

                            </table>
                            <%
                                }
                            %>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <input type="submit" name="btnFinaliseBox" value="Finalise Box" />
```

Servlet:-

```
@WebServlet(name = "AdderCryoboxDeatils96format", urlPatterns = {"/AdderCryoboxDeatils96format"})
```

public class AdderCryoboxDeatils96format extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Barshicohort_sysuser sysUser = (Barshicohort_sysuser) session.getAttribute(MyConstants.SESS_VAR_SYSUSER);

        String btnFinaliseBox = request.getParameter("btnFinaliseBox");
        String strCryoboxBarcode = request.getParameter("txtCryoboxBarcode");

        if (btnFinaliseBox != null) {

            request.setAttribute("txtCryoboxBarcode", strCryoboxBarcode);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddRemark.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String strLocationCtr = request.getParameter("txtLocationCtr");
        String strContentType = request.getParameter("txtContentType");
        String strTypeOfStudy = request.getParameter("txtTypeOfStudy");
        String strSampleStorageCombi = request.getParameter("txtSampleStorageCombination");
        String strRemark = request.getParameter("txtRemark");
        String strStorageTemp = request.getParameter("txtStorageTemp");

        int intLocationCtr = 0;
        if (strLocationCtr == null) {
            strLocationCtr = "0";
            Barshicohortblood_cryoboxmaster obj = new Barshicohortblood_cryoboxmaster();
            obj.setCryoboxBarcode(strCryoboxBarcode);
            obj.setContentType(strContentType);
            obj.setTypeOfStudy(strTypeOfStudy);
            obj.setStorageTemp(strStorageTemp);
            obj.setSampleStorageCombination(strSampleStorageCombi);
            obj.setRemark(strRemark);

            Barshicohortblood_cryoboxmasterDAO dao = new Barshicohortblood_cryoboxmasterDAO();

            if (strCryoboxBarcode.trim().equals("")) {
                request.setAttribute("errMsg", "Cryo box barcode cannot be blank.");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddCryoBoxDeatils.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                return;
            }

            if (!dao.isAvailableCryoBoxBarcode(strCryoboxBarcode)) {
                request.setAttribute("errMsg", "Cryo box already present, Invalid cryobox barcode.");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("AddCryoBoxDeatils.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                return;
            }

            boolean status = dao.add(obj);
            Barshicohortblood_logs logEntity = new Barshicohortblood_logs(strCryoboxBarcode, sysUser.getEmployeeCCNo(), sysUser.getUserCenter(), MyConstants.OPR_ADD);
            new Barshicohortblood_logsDAO().add(logEntity);
            if (status) {
                strLocationCtr = "0";
            }
        } else {
            String strBllodSampleBarcode = request.getParameter("txtBllodSampleBarcode");
            intLocationCtr = Integer.parseInt(strLocationCtr);

            Barshicohortblood_cryoboxescontentDAO contentDAO = new Barshicohortblood_cryoboxescontentDAO();
            Barshicohortblood_vialcontentdataDAO vialDAO = new Barshicohortblood_vialcontentdataDAO();
            Barshicohortblood_vialcontentdata vailcontent = new Barshicohortblood_vialcontentdata();

            Barshicohortblood_cryoboxescontent content = new Barshicohortblood_cryoboxescontent();

            request.setAttribute("txtLocationCtr", "" + intLocationCtr);
            request.setAttribute("txtCryoboxBarcode", strCryoboxBarcode);
            request.setAttribute("txtContentType", strContentType);
            request.setAttribute("txtTypeOfStudy", strTypeOfStudy);
            //request.setAttribute("txtSampleStorageCombi", strSampleStorageCombi);
            request.setAttribute("txtRemark", strRemark);

            if (strBllodSampleBarcode.trim().equals("")) {
                request.setAttribute("errMsg", "Cryo vial barcode cannot be blank.");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("96WellFormatTable.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                return;
            }

            if (!contentDAO.isAvailableCryovialBarcode(strBllodSampleBarcode)) {
                request.setAttribute("errMsg", "Cryo vial already present, Invalid cryovial barcode.");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("96WellFormatTable.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                return;
            }

            if (vialDAO.isAvailableCryovialBarcode(strBllodSampleBarcode)) {
                request.setAttribute("errMsg", " Invalid cryovial barcode.");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("96WellFormatTable.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                return;
            }

                String strTubbarcode = (new Barshicohortblood_vialcontentdataDAO().getByVialBarcode(strBllodSampleBarcode).getTubeBarcode());


            //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            Gen_employee emp = (Gen_employee) session.getAttribute(MyConstants.SESS_VAR_EMPLOYEE);

            String contentId = contentDAO.getFuncCall();
            content.setCryoboxContentId(contentId);
            content.setCryoboxBarcode(strCryoboxBarcode);
            content.setCryoVileBarcode(strBllodSampleBarcode);
            content.setTubeContentDataId(strTubbarcode);                     content.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(strLocationCtr.trim()));
            content.setSacnDate(MyDates.getCurrentMySQLDate());
            content.setScanTime(MyDates.getCurrentMySQLTime());
            content.setEmployeeCCNo(emp.getEmployeeCCNo());

            contentDAO.add(content);

        }


        intLocationCtr++;

        request.setAttribute("txtLocationCtr", "" + intLocationCtr);
        request.setAttribute("txtCryoboxBarcode", strCryoboxBarcode);
        request.setAttribute("txtContentType", strContentType);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("96WellFormatTable.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        return;


    } catch(IllegalStateException e1){
        request.setAttribute("errMsg", " Combination of Cryvial with cryotube alredy present." );
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("96WellFormatTable.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        return;

    } catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
         request.setAttribute("errMsg", " Combination of Cryvial with cryotube alredy present." );
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("96WellFormatTable.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        return;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting error on catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ) on rd.forward(request, response); the error is shown on this line

Error:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.controller.AdderCryoboxDeatils96format.processRequest(AdderCryoboxDeatils96format.java:203)
at org.controller.AdderCryoboxDeatils96format.doGet(AdderCryoboxDeatils96format.java:222)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
```

Comment: keep **e.printStackTrace();** inside the catch block with **SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException** then you will get a better error log showing line numbers of the Java files where Exception occurs and then you can put a debugging point there and see why exception happens

Comment: Thank you, but after writing  e.printStackTrace(); inside it shows the same error on line 203 i.e           rd.forward(request, response);

Comment: enclose **rd.forward(request, response);** (inside the catch with **SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**) within a try and catch with **Exception** type and put a break point inside that catch block. See whether the execution is coming to that break point. If not coming I'm guessing issue is with the jsp. The form action in jsp is give as **AdderCryoboxDeatils96format** shouldn't it be **/AdderCryoboxDeatils96format**

Comment: Thank you @Arun Sudhakaran...It got solved after removing (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) from try

Comment: **Hooray it worked after I removed this!!!**, is the culture followed by most of the new developers. @patil you should take it to consideration that when you removed the code, some issue got fixed, that's temporary but somebody (may be you or not) wrote that code for some reason. Find that reason then do the changes, because after someday may be you may find that some other thing is not working because you removed that code.

Comment: ok...will take a note of this...